# Fragment of how to move to another class using Intent?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments

In Fragment I made a button click handler and using Intent want to go to class Karta, but fails.
Eclipse fail
The constructor Intent(new View.OnClickListener(){}, Class Karta) is undefined
(hlkjbhlkbnkl/nk;/n;kn;/nk;/nk;nk;n)

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {

    Button button1;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1,
                container, false);

        button1=(Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.button1);

        button1.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent (this,Karta.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }});

        return rootView;

    }

}

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Karta extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.karta);

        }
    }
```

Comment: Nevermind. Ahmed's answer is the one you want.

Comment: Log data will be required, and try implementing the OnClickListener interface and overriding on click in main class. The context 'this' used in intent may not be pointing to your activity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 Intent intent = new Intent (Fragment1.this.getActivity(),Karta.class);
```